# Multiple selects without select tag

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need your advice. I have main-list and button. When user presses button I want to show detail-list with items and give him ability to choose several of them.
Then these items will be added to main-list. I want to have ability only to choose items  like in [Selectmenu Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-open) (Shipping method(s)).
but without "select" tag.

How can I implement it? Could you show me correct way?

Other ideas how it can be implemented are welcome.

Thanks,

Comment: Why do you not want to use select tag?

Comment: Select tag doesn't fit me. I have difficult UI.

Comment: Is an `<input type="checkbox" />` ok to use?

Comment: [Jquery Mobile Checkboxes](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/forms/forms-checkboxes.html) - Might be your best bet. Hide it and slideDown or some type of custom popup.

Comment: I implemented it as 2 panels with data-display="overlay". First for main-list, and second for details-list.